# In Visual Studio 2022, how can I run unit tests and run a localhost server simultaneously? - Testing a WebAPI on localhost

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I have VS2022 Solution with 2 projects

1. I have a .net core WebAPI project - that when runs on localhost:5001. This works fine ,
   API works etc..
2. I have another project, a .net core console - with the unit tests.

*I have tried ChatGPT for a solution. But several of the ChatGPT recommendations do not work*. I setup up the solution for multiple startups. Solution runs,  WebAPI swagger pops up , I see the Text Explorer, looks like it running - but I can not select any of the Test Explore options or debug the tests.

ChatGPT recommended the following.. but it doesn't work, I can't select or debug my tests. Also They fail immediately saying it can't locate the localhost/port. Could it be a timing issue?

**Any ideas how I can run unit tests simultaneously with localhost** ?

Here's the ChatGPT instructions - but I can't select the Test Explorer or debug the tests.
Any ideas?

```
In Visual Studio 2022, you can run unit tests and run a localhost server simultaneously by following these steps:

Make sure your unit tests are set up correctly in your Visual Studio project. You should have a separate project or folder dedicated to unit tests.

Open your solution in Visual Studio 2022.

Right-click on the solution in the Solution Explorer and select "Properties" from the context menu.

In the properties window, go to the "Startup Project" tab.

Select the option "Multiple startup projects."

In the list of projects, select the project that contains your unit tests and the project that runs your localhost server. You can use Ctrl+Click to select multiple projects.

Set the action for both projects to "Start."

Click "Apply" and then "OK" to save the changes.

Press F5 or click the "Start" button to run your solution.

**Visual Studio will now start both the unit test project and the project running your localhost server simultaneously. You'll be able to see the output from both projects in the Output window, and you can interact with your localhost server while the unit tests are running.**
```

Comment: Is Web API project build using .NET (Core) also (i.e. it is ASP.NET Core one)?

Comment: In short - you should not start an API on localhost (at least manually) for unit test - use the [integration test approach from the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/test/integration-tests?view=aspnetcore-7.0)

Comment: Yes.. all core.